How to Develop Applications for Google Home Devices in 2024
I have been working on creating an Alexa Skill as part of a larger project. Now, I need to develop a similar application for Google Home devices. Initially, I thought this would be straightforward since the underlying logic wouldn’t change much. However, after extensive research, I’m unsure where to start.
Here's what I've found so far:

Google Developer Console: I initially thought Google Actions would be the right choice, but it has been deprecated for a year.
Dialogflow: I discovered this service, but it appears to be considered legacy.
Google Home Developer Console: This seems to be intended for integrating specific products (e.g., smart lightbulbs) with Google Home's API.

At this point, I’m quite lost and unsure how to proceed. Is there an updated service or platform provided by Google for building applications for their smart devices (Google Home, Google Hub, etc.), similar to Amazon's Alexa Skills Console? Any guidance on the current tools and frameworks available for this purpose would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

You can go through the steps mentioned in the following codelab, to get a proper understanding as to how to create an application for Google Home Devices.
The above document provides a step by step guidance about how to connect smart devices to Google Assistant.
